# How to get rid of white edges

Tags: image-editing, paint.net

I want to tessellate using Paint.net. When I clone an image, it comes out with a white "shadow" around the whole edge (see attached image). In MSPaint, all I have to do is hit the "transparent" button to get rid of the "shadow," but in paint.net, I don't know how.

[image: transparent]

Comment: Fabulous, Tetsujin!  How did you do that?

Comment: You might get a better response on [graphicdesign.se].